# Why do frozen fishes have incision in the body?

Tags: fish

I've bought a lot of frozen fishes say a pompano or mackerels. I've noticed that whenever i defrost the fishes, all of them have a small incision in the stomach and these fishes are almost never bled out. Can someone tell me why is there an incision? Because it makes cleaning a lot harder for me.

Comment: But the fish do have their guts (for lack of a better word) removed, don't they?

Comment: I hope they have had their guts removed.  However, a lot of fishermen now instantly freeze fish on board without gutting them first.  This is not good, a fish should be bled and gutted asap.  As for the incisions, are they all in the same place, could it be from a hook (mackerel)?

Comment: @Jude, no they do not. I have to gut them myself.

Comment: @dougal2.0.0, yes they are.

Comment: Ah nameless, if you are buying frozen fish still with the guts, then perhaps you shouldn't!  Sorry really can't add anything else to this.  I do a lot of fishing (trawling from the back of the boat), and thus gut and scale the fish myself.  I am not that 'au-fait' with the frozen variety.

Comment: @dougal2.0.0, is it bad ? I mean I can do it myself, but I just find it annoying when they make the incision already for me because they do it in the middle. Normally you go up to the gills or fin and cut down from there.

Comment: As I understand it, bacteria from the gut infiltrates the flesh if fish is not gutted asap.  Also transference of taste.  Perhaps try buying a different brand next time, or go for pre-gutted fish.

Comment: @dougal2.0.0, argh no wonder that fish didn't have much taste. It was rather bland.

Comment: A guess but to let gas escape.

Comment: I wouldn't buy fish that wasn't gutted already, makes me wonder what other corners they cut...

Comment: No idea why there's an incision but I want to add my voice to the others. Don't buy ungutted frozen fish! You *may* never get ill from eating them but it's like never being in an accident so the person feels no need to wear a seatbelt. Not worth the risk.

Comment: Custom will vary in different places and for different varieties, but around here, if a fish is frozen without offal and gills remove, it is likely intended for bait or possibly animal use, not human consumption.  That is almost always going to lead to off smell, a bitter, bile taste and must faster spoilage.  The puncture could be a number of reasons such as the fish were harvested by snagging or as suggested to puncture for gassing which would also mean they were not even fresh when frozen.

Comment: I wouldn't buy that brand again; fish should either be frozen whole or (preferably) frozen gutted. That the belly was slit but the guts not removed indicates a failure in processing, and where there's one failure, there's likely others.