# Why was fish cut open at supermarket?

Tags: fish

I bought some whole mackerel at the supermarket yesterday and I found when I opened the package that the fish had had their belly cut open but they had not been cleaned. Obviously it is really bad to do that because bacteria and parasites that exist in the intestines of the fish can contaminate any surface that is exposed to that mess. In fact two small worms had actually crawled out and were on the outside of the fish.

Why would the supermarket do that?

Comment: This question reminds me of another asked Feb. 5, 2017 [why do frozen fishes have incisions?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/78132/why-do-frozen-fishes-have-incision-in-the-body) The other fish was frozen, but also ungutted it sounded like. Don't know if it is related to your circumstance, but *mackerel* was also mentioned. It looks like that question never got a real answer, but there was much speculation and sharing of advice, which might be of interest to you.

Comment: I'll make sure to ask the fishmonger here next time I see him and will try to remember to post back here. That sounds suspect and a strange, unnecessary practice indeed. I'd go back to the market and request money back or at least an explanation (unless it was not store brand ofc). Hope you threw it out with worms on it!

Comment: hmm; you probably don't want to know the answer to this.  Worked at a supermarket that is now thankfully closed many years ago in teen years.  Re-packaging older fish and wiping worms off was a practice and would explain some of what you saw.  

Also keep in mind 90% of that fish in "fresh" area is usually just defrosted from frozen area and re-packaged and price raised.  Be sure to check carefully.

Personally I don't source fish from any bargain supermarkets anymore.